# What is the meaning of "the bigger risk is doing nothing"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was reading [this](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/bill-ford-interview-vision-for-world-without-cars/) article on Wired website which I think it quotes this sentence from Bill Ford:

> The bigger risk is doing nothing.

I wonder what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example -- If your house is on the beach and a hurricane is coming, you could stay at your house and prepare the house for the hurricane.  You could leave and stay at a hotel far from the beach, or you could do nothing.  "The bigger risk is doing nothing."  You have a greater exposure or more danger if you chose to do nothing.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @KittyConsltant I got it.  It means doing nothing is a bigger risk.  I wonder how I missed it 

Comment: In a situation with more than two choices, such as yours, I would say *the biggest risk is...*